# Comparing jQuery (javascript?) Events for Equal Origin Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm comparing `click` events in jQuery to see if they fired from the same click. Right now I'm using the events' `timeStamp` to test to see if the events came from the same click, and while this will almost certainly work, I'm wondering if there's a better way.

For example, if `body` and `header` both have a click event, and I click on the `header`, it will bubble up to the `body`. What is the best way to test if both events that fire come from the same click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain JavaScript, the same event object will reach both event listeners, so [you can compare them](http://jsfiddle.net/uaZH7/). jQuery on the other hand will wrap the original event object into a new normalized object for each listener, so you have to [check their `.originalEvent` property](http://jsfiddle.net/EJzbW/) instead.

In any case, I never needed to check for that. Usually, you just want to know if the clicked element is the same as the one you bound the click to, or not:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target === this) {
        // the click happened on the body itself
    } else {
        // the click bubbled up
    }
}, false);
```

jQuery provides a nice mechanism for event delegation, so you don't even need the `if`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.someSelector', function(e) {
    // This will only fire if an element with class 'someSelector'
    // was clicked
});
```

Comment: oh man, is it seriously just `e.originalEvent`? How did I miss that!?

Comment: But do you really need to compare the events like that? What are you trying to achieve? Consider the code at the end of my answer (the jquery equivalent is very similar).

Comment: I have a complex need, but I can think of a few not complex ones. Let's say that I want to dynamically create a `div` on the page when I click a button, and when I create that `div`, I want to assign a `click` to the `body` that will remove that `div`. The problem could arise that clicking on the button would create a `div`, but then the event would bubble up to the body and remove it. I could `stopPropagation` on the button, but what if I needed the event to bubble up? I just would want to check to make sure that the create div button click isn't the same click as the remove div body click.

Comment: @MattDiamant See my update, it sounds like you just need the standard way to use event delegation with `.on` in jQuery.